# Adding text to Toggle Menu of a Persistent Drawer in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, drawer

I would like to add some text in the area (which I've circled) that has the toggle button for persistent drawers. Is this possible? If so, how would I implement this?

[image]

I looked through Stack Overflow and Material UI's documentation and there appears to be no answers to this question of mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add any text you want in `DrawerHeader` component like this (in this case "**custom header text**"):

```
<DrawerHeader>
  custom header text
  <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
    {theme.direction === "ltr" ? (
      <ChevronLeftIcon />
    ) : (
      <ChevronRightIcon />
    )}
  </IconButton>
</DrawerHeader>
```

You can take a look at [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mui-drawer-header?file=src%2FApp.tsx) for a live working example.